why won’t my baby leopard gecko eat?
my baby leopard gecko won’t eat his temper is good in the 70 gallon tank and he has baby crickets and meal worms all he has been doing is sleeping and not eating what should I do ? He already finished shedding .

This question is similar to: Baby leopard gecko won't eat!. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
